# Dual Boot Windows 10 with Ubuntu

Tags: windows, dual-boot, elementary-os

I recently bought a new SSD drive for my PC and would like to install a version of [ubuntu](https://elementary.io/) on it. I installed the drive and managed to get the OS on the SSD but when I boot the PC I'm given no option to choose which OS to use. My boot manager is called ASROCK Boot UEFI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no bootloader shows up in the boot process, this could be because you installed the bootloader on your ssd. Go into bios and tell bios to boot into your ssd instead of booting into your other harddrive where windows is installed.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
sudo update-grub
```

and see if windows is detected

Comment: Hi @Guillaume, Thanks for replying, At the moment i cant access elementary OS. I can only boot into windows

Comment: In this case you want to boot with [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) (boot via usb or cd), and choose: Recommanded Repair.

Answer (score 0):

You can always modify windows so that it loads the ubuntu bootloader instead of it's own. In windows, just open up cmd as admin, then enter:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

Make sure that this is actually the right path for the elementary OS bootloader, otherwise your system might not boot at all anymore.

Comment: Hi @Nordic can you tell me first how to check in windows the path? I just want to be 100% sure i don't brick the system

Comment: No idea unfortunately, I'm not too familiar with windows when it comes to lowlevel stuff. If I were you I'd just go and ask someone in an elementary OS forum if they can find out if that's the correct file for elementary or not. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You must type msconfig in the command prompt, start tab, choose "normal boot". Reboot and there you can access the secure boot options normally, which are otherwise grayed out. From there you can choose shimx64 or grubx64. Then the boot will be possible.
I had a hard time finding but I got there.